# Custom sound notifications in Android and setSound is not working

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to play custom sound notifications in Android.
I have mentioned that in notification channel, but setSound is not working.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val existingChannel=notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(id)
    if(existingChannel!=null)
        {notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(id)}
    val channel = NotificationChannel(id, name, importance)        
        channel.description = description
        channel.enableLights(true)
        channel.setShowBadge(true)
        channel.setBypassDnd(dnd)
        channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
        channel.lightColor = R.color.cornflower_blue_dark
        channel.enableVibration(true) 
        channel.setSound(path,
               AudioAttributes.Builder()
                  .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                  .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_EVENT)
                  .build())
     notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(channel)
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Deepashree Mulay, Can you format your code to become more readable? That will make you chances to get proper answer here much higher.